# How to fill dataset using LINQ with FillDataSet(ds) Method c#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

How to fill dataset using LINQ with FillDataSet(ds) Method.  When iam trying to implement this code iam getting error like FillDataSet does not exist in current context.

My code is

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable products = ds.Tables["emp"];

IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from product in dtContext.emps.AsEnumerable()
    select product;
```

Please tell me how to fill dataset with FillDataSet(ds) Method.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `FillDataSet` method in your code? if yes, then what is the access specifier to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have* to fill a `DataSet` with LINQ2SQL. Nor do you have to use `DataTable` etc. All you need is the data context and perform queries on that:

```
var query = from product in dtContext.emps
            select product;
```

`query` will be of type `IQueryable<T>` and you can use e.g. a `foreach` on it to go through its content, or filter it further with a `where` clause. Why do you want a `DataSet`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your `FillDataSet(DatatSet ds)` method. Probably you should implement something similar to this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399340.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) if you are following the MSDN tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

From your post

> FillDataSet does not exist in current context.

It clearly means that it cant access the FillDataSet method or else your method doesnt exist.

If it exists, then try changing the access specifier to `public` if it is in different class.

PS: did you declare any method named `FillDataSet` ?