# Add Linq to dataset ( i can't FillDataset)

Tags: c#, linq

my simple code is :

> my button generate Report

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        // i can't type "FillDataSet(ds)" it can't shown
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls"; 

        IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from db in Program.data.Transactions.AsEnumerable() where db.StartDate == dateTimePicker1.Value.Date  select db;

        DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

i can't use fillDataSet, any one knows why?

i use :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.DataRowExtensions;
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: `FillDataSet` doesn't exist. Are you looking at some code sample that is using a `FillDataSet` method and expecting it to be available to your code?

Comment: yeah, can you show me?

Comment: Have you tried `ds.Tables.Add(boundTable);` ?

Comment: [How to fill dataset using LINQ with FillDataSet(ds) Method c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527247/how-to-fill-dataset-using-linq-with-filldatasetds-method-c-sharp)